# Android wear emulator crashes on startup

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I'm trying to develop an Android wear application, using Android studio.  Everything was going fine until I was requested to make an update a few days ago (unfortunately I do not remember what the exact update was, but I think it actually had to do with Android studio, but I might be wrong about that)

Anyway:  After the update, my application does not start properly in the emulator.  The emulator fires up as it should, but then shows a screen where it says that my app has stopped and shows a reload button.  When I press the reload button the app starts as it should.

Does anybody know why I can't get my app to start right away?

I found an error message in logical that says:
       android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.google.android.clockwork.home2.module.watchfacepicker.AllFacesView

Also, I have tried to limit my activity xml to just the bare layout at the top level, but I still get the same behavior...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this was downvoted.  I'm getting the same error in almost all my emulators, except mine is showing Android Wear crashing not my app.  I'm able to bring up my app if I run it, then hit he back button on the emulator.

Something to do with the the Watch Face picker.